# Show that Co(K) is a compact subset of $ R^n $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let K be a compact subset of $ R ^ n $. The set Co (K) defined by:
$ Co:= \left \lbrace{z = tx + (1-t) y \in R ^ n: x, y \in K ,  t \in \left [0,1 \right]}\right \rbrace $

Show that Co(K) is a compact subset of $ R^n $

I have the following ideas:

Consider a sequence $ \left \lbrace {z_ {n}} \right \rbrace_{n} \in N $ of points of Co(K)

$zn:= t_ {n} x_ {n} + (1-t_n) y_ {n} $

Notice that $ y_{n} $ and $ x_{n} $ are contained in K and $ t_{n} \in \left [0,1 \right] $. Since K is a compact subset and $ \left [0,1 \right] $ is also compact, there are convergent subsucessions whose limit belongs to K and $ \left [0,1 \right] $.

What I do not know is how I take the subsucessions so that their limit is contained in Co (K) and implies compactness, any suggestion will be very useful, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Note that his definition of $\mathrm{Co}(K)$ is not the convex hull of $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gae. S. 's answer is arguably the fastest way to prove the result. I present another solution, closer to what OP tried.

Let $(x_{\phi_1(n)})$ be a converging subsequence of $(x_n)$, $(y_{\phi_1\circ\phi_2(n)})$ a converging subsequence of $(y_{\phi_1(n)})$ and $(t_{\phi_1\circ\phi_2\circ\phi_3(n)})$ a converging subsequence of $(t_{\phi_1\circ\phi_2(n)})$.

Then set $\phi = \phi_1 \circ \phi_2 \circ \phi_3$ and notice that $(x_{\phi(n)})$, $(y_\phi(n))$ and $(t_{\phi(n)})$ are convergent, with limits $x,y \in K$ and $t\in[0,1]$ respectively. Now we have :
$$\lim z_{\phi(n)} = tx + (1-t)y \in \operatorname{Co}(K)$$

Answer (score 5):

$\operatorname{Co}(K)$ is the image of the compact set $K\times K\times [0,1]$ by the continuous map $(a,b,t)\mapsto ta+(1-t)b$.